# How to replace a light bulb in ceiling light

Tags: lightning

[image: Puzzling light]

So I have those lights out of which most lightbulbs burned down, thus I want to replace them. Problem is that I have no idea how to get to them, tried to pull down the entire thing - but that just pulls down the entire "socket", tried to pry the "metal rim" with a flat top but that also didn't seem right, and I didn't want to possibly ruin it so I gave up.

Any ideas on how to get in and replace the bulbs? Also what type of bulb may it be so I can order replacements?

Comment: Did you try pushing gently on the glass & turning counter-clockwise?

Comment: @brhans yep, no luck on either of the sockets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That looks like an old school can/recessed light which utilized flood light style bulbs. You should be able to apply slight pressure with your finger tips while turning counter clockwise to loosen/remove the bulb.

Comment: yes, you should be able to unscrew the light bulb with finger pressure, or maybe try to find a suction cup that will grip the exposed surface of the bulb.

Comment: I just gave that a try and no luck, and just to be sure tried on few different bulbs as they are indeed quite old. Guess can go and buy a suction cup tomorrow and see if that will do.

Comment: @TymoteuszPaul - if you can't get it with your hands, I doubt a cup will help you. Those lights get really hot and are probably fused to the the paint on the escutcheon and to the socket to some extent. Go nuts and when you break it, go buy LED replacement 'can' lights to cover the hole.

Comment: @Mazura aw, not the answer I was hoping for. Ah well, thanks for that and guess will go shopping for someone to come and replace the lights with leds. Accepting the answer as it's correct, at least in theory of it ;).

Comment: @Mazura those don't get so hot, those are CFLs.  You can see the screwball behind the bezel.